# How to keep the jolie service up an running?

Tags: jolie

I have a glossary service (jolie service) that provides the definitions based on the input terms. I start this service in the usual way :

```
jolie ./Glossary.ol
```

The issue is that the service exits as soon as the first request is served. To get the definition of another term, I need to start the service again.

How do I keep the service running? Once I do that, what are the options to stop the service (other than Ctrl+C)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `concurrent` `execution` modality, guarded choices (the syntax `[ input ]{ post-response code }`, and the `exit` instruction.
Here's a simple example (imports, ports, and services omitted for brevity).

```
// client.ol
main {
  for( i=0, i<10, nullProcess ){
    inc@server( i )( i )
    println@Console( i )()
  }
  shutdown@server()()
}
```

```
// server.ol
execution{ concurrent }

main {
  [ inc( i )( i ){
    println@Console( "received " + i + ", sending " + ++i )()
  } ]
  [ shutdown()() ]{ exit }
}
```

Comment: thanks. `execution { concurrent }` works. But, when I add the shutdown call, I get this error.  `invalid identifier: shutdown
java.lang.ClassCastException: class jolie.process.NullProcess cannot be cast to class jolie.process.InputOperationProcess (jolie.process.NullProcess and jolie.process.InputOperationProcess are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

Comment: I should see the whole example to give an accurate answer, however, from what I can see it seems like `shutdown` is missing from the `interface` the service is exposing. Is the `shutdown` operation included in the interface exposed by the inputPort?

Comment: You are right. While trying a lot of options, I had removed shutdown form the interface but then included the call in the main method. Thanks for your analysis.